# ZTE router antihacking option

Tags: router

I have a ZTE Modem router using it to get internet connection for a home PC, I opened the tab : security and under it choosed "firewall".

I found that the option : "enable anti hacking" is unchecked.
According to ZTE help, checking this option protects against (ping flood, ping to death, sync flood attacks).

And I found the option " Firewall level" is set to high, and a small hint below it is written as follows : "Allow legal WAN side access, but prohibit Ping from WAN side."

I checked the " enable anti hacking " option.

But I'm asking, I there a possibility that I have been hacked in the period before I enable this option or this is impossible because the firewall is set to high which prevents WAN ping?

The router model is " ZXHN H108N V2.5"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The help for the "anti hacking" feature you show only describes some trivial attacks which are no problem for most modern systems anyway or, in the case of SYN flood, at most make the system very slow (i.e. denial of service). This feature in no way protects against the most common attacks against clients today, i.e. malware, ransomware, banking trojans etc delivered through phishing mails, malicious ads or malicious or hacked web sites.
In other words: it is more marketing than useful.